# How to load Posts from one Wordpress Website to another wordpress website?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I have **Two (2) Wordpress** websites, both running on same VPS Server. Although, different domain names. All I need to do is, insert **Post Grid** in my **Website 1** and add **5 Most Recent Posts** from **Website 2**. If a user clicks on a post, it will redirect to **Website 2** and open the post. **All these post Must be automatically updated, when I updates Website 2.**

I have searched over internet but there was no any explanation (also I couldn't search exactly what I want.) Any information about a **Plugin** or any help would be highly welcome.! Thank you in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality by RSS import, refer below for plugin,

REF : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-aggregator/ 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/rss-post-importer/

Comment: Thank you very much..!! This is what I was looking for..!! But there is still a small problem.. I have no experience in RSS. All I need to do is show post from my one site in another. Are these plugins can do that? Or what types of plugins should I look for..? Thank u again..!!